# What is a "featured site" in the context of open data?

Tags: data.gov

Is open data a government initiative or are there non-government sites such as [Project Gutenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Gutenberg) that are part of open data? How does a "featured site" work? Is it somehow linked to data.gov, or does it operate independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While open government initiatives are often led by governments and their agencies, non-governmental groups are participating in open government programs.

Resources: 
https://www.whitehouse.gov/open
http://www.opengovpartnership.org/